# Calculating residues with congruence

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I have to calculate the resiude of $41^{65}$ dividing by $7$. I know that we can calculating the size $k$ of the cycle of the powers of $41^n$ with $n=1,2,\ldots$ then by clasificating the residues with the $k$ clases we only use $65\equiv r(\mod k)$ and then we finish. But... $41$ is a prime number an the power are too big with $n=3,4,...$ Are there some hint of result that simplifies this problem? Any helop would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $41\equiv ?\pmod 7$...

Comment: The resul is $6$ That is the size of $k$? if this is true why?

Comment: You can also say that $6\equiv -1\pmod 7$...

Comment: So $41^{65}\equiv(-1)^{65}\pmod 7$...

Comment: Oh... that's right...

Answer (score 0):

By Fermat's Little Theorem,
$$a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$$ where $p$ is a prime and $p$ does not divide $a$, we may observe a cyclic pattern for the base 41 with respect to 7. To start,
$$41^0\equiv1\pmod7$$
Multiplying by 41:
$$41^1\equiv6\pmod7$$
Repeating
$$41^2\equiv6\times41\pmod7\implies41^2\equiv1\pmod7$$
By this we see that for any exponent of 41, the remainder with respect to 7 is either 6 or 1, this should simplify your problem.